# Failing to get individual boxplot intervals for sample locations for phylosq object

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, phyloseq

I have a phyloseq object containg an otu_table, tax_table and sam_data.`physeq` is the phyloseq object.

I want to use following code:

```
plot_richness(physeq, x ="Location" , measures = c("Observed", "Shannon")) + geom_boxplot()
```

Location is a column in sam_data with location 1,2,3 and 4, with each of my 100 samples associated with one location.

This is the plot i'm getting:
[One boxplot for observed and one for shannon. I want 4 boxplots in both.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTUhE.png)

I also keep geting a warning:

```
Warning message:
Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
```

I have seen identical code with the correct result without using aes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning message tells you that `Location` is a continuous numeric variable. You should convert `Location` to a factor or character before calling `plot_richness` Here's an example using `GlobalPatterns`.

```r
require("phyloseq")
require("ggplot2")

# Load data
data("GlobalPatterns")
sample_data(GlobalPatterns)$Location <- sample(c(1, 2, 3, 4), nsamples(GlobalPatterns), replace = T)
plot_richness(GlobalPatterns, x = "Location", measures = c("Shannon", "Observed")) +
  geom_boxplot()
#> Warning: Continuous x aesthetic -- did you forget aes(group=...)?
```

[image]

```r
# Update to factor
sample_data(GlobalPatterns)$Location <- as.factor(sample_data(GlobalPatterns)$Location)
plot_richness(GlobalPatterns, x = "Location", measures = c("Shannon", "Observed")) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I also found a different solution. By typing geom_boxplot(aes(group=Location))